# Am I correctly importing the pyqt module library? Execution returns error "module called qdialog is not found"

Tags: python, module, pyqt, pyqt5, qtgui

I tried to run this code and it says a module called `qdialog` is not found.

```
import sys  # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication
import commentAnalyzer
import design
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDialog, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import SIGNAL
```

I tried to run this and I got:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QDialog' from 'PyQt5.QtGui'
```

Comment: QDialog, QPushButton, QLabel are in QtWidgets not in QtGui

Comment: Also you're importing everything from QtCore and after that importing SIGNAL from QtCore. That's redundant and SIGNAL does not exist. It's pyqtSiganal

Comment: It seems you're trying to adapt a code originally written for PyQt4. Do some research on the topic, starting from https://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the import like below

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
```

QDialog is inside QtWidgets

Answer (score 0):

This are the imports without redundancy and non-existent modules:

```
import sys
import commentAnalyzer
import design

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
```